# How Can I Create an HTML Page with the Subscriber Attributes in the Correct Order?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, php

I am retrieving the Subscriber from the API.

The Marketing Cloud advertises an Order field in the Profile Management section, that allows attributes to be ordered. Also, there is a "Hidden" checkbox in the properties dialog box for an attribute to be hidden from the subscriber.

Issue: Unfortunately, the Order integer, and the Hidden boolean are not provided in the response from the API.  There seems to be some missing data in the response from the API, because it is not a reflection of the Profile Management section in the Marketing Cloud.

Use-case: I'm building a custom preference center that is integrated with the ExactTarget API.  The preference center is using a content engine to dynamically write the HTML using the data retrieved via the API Call.  Because I am relying on the ExactTarget API for the data, I'm hoping the API would have the ability to reference the Order and Hidden fields in the response, so I can iterate over these objects and print their values through my PHP engine.

--

Is it possible to add these extra values into the Attributes of the Soap Response?

--

Proposed Solution:

```
[Results] => Array
    (
        [PartnerKey] => 
        [ID] => 0000000000
        [ObjectID] => 
        [EmailAddress] => someone@mail.com
        [Attributes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => Email Address
                        [Value] => someone@mail.com
                        [Order] => 4
                        [Hidden] => FALSE
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => First Name
                        [Value] => John
                        [Order] => 1
                        [Hidden] => FALSE
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => Interest Level
                        [Value] => 75%
                        [Order] => 3
                        [Hidden] => TRUE
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => Last Name
                        [Value] => Smith
                        [Order] => 2
                        [Hidden] => FALSE
                    )

            )

        [SubscriberKey] => someone@mail.com
        [Status] => Active
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ListAttribute` object returns the `Ordinal` property for this -

**Sample Request**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Header>  
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">your api key</fueloauth>
    </Header> 
       <Body>
          <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
             <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>ListAttribute</ObjectType> 
                <Properties>Name</Properties> 
                <Properties>Ordinal</Properties>    
             </RetrieveRequest>
          </RetrieveRequestMsg>
       </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Sample Response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:4052ca74-1c5b-4d89-bfff-daecb764484f</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:589c0c8c-5309-40b9-bf1e-ea58ac8274c2</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-351a200d-f58e-474c-b3e5-333c43f6a826">
            <wsu:Created>2014-04-25T10:22:30Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-04-25T10:27:30Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>e31df1ab-2c43-4425-bf26-450d7ceb31b0</RequestID>
         <Results xsi:type="ListAttribute">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Name>_ModifiedDate</Name>
            <Ordinal>19</Ordinal>
         </Results>
         <Results xsi:type="ListAttribute">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>
            <Ordinal>1</Ordinal>
         </Results>
         <Results xsi:type="ListAttribute">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Name>FullName</Name>
            <Ordinal>2</Ordinal>
         </Results>
      <!-- results continue -->
      </RetrieveResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You should be able to use this in building out the profile center.

**Edit**
[Link to `ListAttribute` docs](http://help.exacttarget.com/fr/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listattribute/)

Comment: Hey Kelly, thank you for providing me this solution for the ordinal.  Will it also describe an attribute as hidden?

Comment: Yes absolutely - updated with link to the ListAttribute object.

Comment: Did this answer your question,  or no?

Comment: That information is wonderful.  Is the Subscriber Object also getting these changes in its Attributes property, which contains the Attribute objects?  I'm trying to minimize my calls to the API.  Would really benefit from having the Attributes property in the Subscriber object reflect those changes as well :)  Let me know if it can be done.  Gracias.

Comment: `Subscriber` object will show what the attributes are, but the ordinal property is only on the `ListAttribute` object. You would want to call for the `ListAttribute` to get the attributes, then populate with the `Subscriber` object.

Comment: Totally get it - you can always submit that info to your RM, or in the 3Sixty section under ideas.

Comment: Just added to the ideas section.  Thanks again for supporting us.

Comment: I ran a call on the ListAttribute for all objects on the account, and it returned a lot of objects, but I couldn't find the attributes on the AllSubscribers list.  In fact, it seemed to be listing fields in the Data Extensions.  Is there an example of a call to the ListAttribute retrieve that is able to return the attributes from the profile management section of the Marketing Cloud with Ordinal, isHidden, etc?  Again, the results seem to exclude simple list attributes from Profile Management.

Comment: Can you add the SOAP packet to your question above?  The initial result probably needs filtered, but should have your list attributes available.  The above is just an example of how you might run it.